# Socket.io chat app that can also send image and even file

Tags: javascript, node.js, encoding, websocket, socket.io

I've been interested in the `Socket.io` project recently and I wonder if there's easy way to send image or even other type of files without having to use other library. I'm not trying to upload the file to the server to store, I just want to broadcast it to those who are in the chat room at that moment. So the code should be minimal. However I'm really bad at encoding/decoding stuff, so some example code would be great.

Answer (score 13):

I've adapted the official chat example of Socket.io and added functionality of sending file/images and even videos through base64 encoding, you can have a look at the source code in `client.js` and `index.js`, below are the most relevant part, hope it's helpful to you.

On client side:

```
$('#uploadfile').bind('change', function(e){
    var data = e.originalEvent.target.files[0];
    readThenSendFile(data);      
});

function readThenSendFile(data){

    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(evt){
        var msg ={};
        msg.username = username;
        msg.file = evt.target.result;
        msg.fileName = data.name;
        socket.emit('base64 file', msg);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(data);
}
```

On server side:

```
socket.on('base64 file', function (msg) {
    console.log('received base64 file from' + msg.username);
    socket.username = msg.username;
    // socket.broadcast.emit('base64 image', //exclude sender
    io.sockets.emit('base64 file',  //include sender

        {
          username: socket.username,
          file: msg.file,
          fileName: msg.fileName
        }

    );
});
```

Here's the project:

https://github.com/Arch1tect/Chatbox

Comment: I'm having problem sending pdf 3mb ~ 4MB to download! network failure! I need compress the file? your code is sending base64 freely, would be this the problem?

Comment: @FábioZangirolami Does it work if you send smaller file like 1 MB or 100kb? If so it might be a problem with heartbeat, socket.io send heartbeat to check if user is still connected, if user doesn't respond to the heartbeat in 60 secs they are disconnected by the server. The problem is that when sending file, heartbeat is blocked, so this can happen.

Comment: Smaller files work! I solved the problem using uploadfile instead of base64.. tks!!

Comment: @FábioZangirolami i m sending images using the base64 method now, and my chat server disconnects when image is over 3 mb and its width and height are above 1K. Can you please share how did u use the uploadfile method with socket io to send images from client to server?

Comment: @Faizan I did it using the library. var formidable = require('formidable'); // file upload module

Comment: Thanks @FábioZangirolami i will try that, there r multiple of them, my chat app is on node express socket io, so may be this will work fine for me?  https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-formidable , there r other versions too https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable  https://www.npmjs.com/package/socketio-file-upload , my aim is to allow users to upload images, videos, files in my chat app over socket io and show it to clients in realtime in HTML5.  Right now i m sendiing images in base 64 but larger images is crashing the socket io chat. Can u share s working code e.g using formidable?